# How to validate password and confirm password using angular 12 material?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I would like a lot of help from you. I'm not able to validate the password field and confirm password using angular material in version 12. I'm using this structure below in html.

```html
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput 
           type="password" 
           placeholder="Digite sua senha" 
           [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
           [formControl]="passwordFormControl" />
    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">
           {{ hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off' }}
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-error>               
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Confirm Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput
           type="password" 
           placeholder="Digite novamente sua senha"
           [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" 
           [formControl]="passwordFormControl"/>
    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">
      {{ hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off' }}
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-error>               
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Custom Validation: Password Confirmation

Mustafa is right that you're better off using reactive forms when you are using Angular Material and the `mat-error` tags. However, here is a more complete version including all the validation messages, since you asked for **'A LOT OF'** help.

I improved the Mustafa's validator a little too. This will help you get rid of all weirdness with the validation messages.

The visibility icon logic was removed since material password inputs already have this functionality built in.

Script:

```js
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group(
    {
      password: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(100),
        ],
      ],
      confirmPassword: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(100),
        ],
      ],
    },
    { validator: CustomValidators.MatchingPasswords }
  );
}
```

The improved custom validator:

```js
export class CustomValidators {

    static MatchingPasswords(control: AbstractControl) {
        const password = control.get('password').value;
        const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword').value;
        const currentErrors = control.get('confirmPassword').errors
        const confirmControl = control.get('confirmPassword')

        if (compare(password, confirmPassword)) {
            confirmControl.setErrors({...currentErrors, not_matching: true});
        } else {
            confirmControl.setErrors(currentErrors)
        }
    }
}

function compare(password: string,confirmPassword: string) {
    return password !== confirmPassword && confirmPassword !== ''
}
```

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      formControlName="password"
    />
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('required')">
      Password is required!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('minlength')">
      Password should be longer than 8 characters!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('password').hasError('maxlength')">
      Password can't be longer than 100 characters!
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Confirm Password</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Confirm your password..."
      formControlName="confirmPassword"
      type="password"
    />
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').hasError('required')">
      Password confirmation is required!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').hasError('minlength')">
      Password should be longer than 8 characters!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').hasError('maxlength')">
      Password can't be longer than 100 characters!
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('confirmPassword').hasError('not_matching')">
      The password doesn't match!
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

*You can clean up all the `mat-error` tags, by providing the message with a function.*

Here's an example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqcju3?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you to play with.

Comment: Thank you very much H3AR7B3A7, As I said above, I made your example that was much more complete and it worked perfectly. I just got an error in my form: FormGroup; and as suggested by vscode, I added a "!" in front, looking like this: form!: FormGroup;

Comment: @Leogomes Using a Definite Assignment (!) is perfectly fine when you provide an initialization for a declaration in either the `constructor` or `ngOnInit`. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-9raszv?file=angular-fourteen/src/app/app.component.ts)'s another more refine version in **Angular 14**, using the new **Strongly-Typed Reactive Form** and **Standalone Components**, including some improvements to the code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the reactive form to validate. this is how you form structure will look like [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kingsbury-angular-w-material-n7z9wh?file=src/app/app.component.html) you can take care of other styling and all

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    ....rest
) { }
this.form=this.fb.group({
           .... other enteries
           password: ['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(8),
                Validators.maxLength(100)
            ])
            ],
            confirmPassword: ['', Validators.compose([
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(8),
                Validators.maxLength(100)
            ])
 },{ validator: ConfirmPasswordValidator.MatchPassword})
```

This is how your validator will look

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ConfirmPasswordValidator {
    /**
     * Check matching password with confirm password
     * @param control AbstractControl
     */
    static MatchPassword(control: AbstractControl) {
        const password = control.get('password').value;

        const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword').value;

        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            control.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ConfirmPassword: true});
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that reactive forms work a lot better when using mat-error to show validation errors. I hope you don't mind I improved your validator a little. Returning null and not retaining the existing errors creates some weirdness with the validation messages if there is more than 1 validation.

Comment: Mustafá Kunwa.  Thank you very much for your readiness. I did as the demo of H3AR7B3A7 and it worked. You helped me a lot. It generated an error in my scenario and I made a change that I don't know if it's right, but it worked. In H3AR7B3A7's answer, it was with <
  form: FormGroup; > This way it generated an error for me and I adjusted to
  < form!: FormGroup; >, in this way, the error disappeared and it worked.